# How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card, microphone

I can record sounds using my mic, however I cannot hear my voice through the speakers.
I have a realtek card (I have a ACER one notebook).
I have been reading a lot of information in the web but I cant make it work.
I am missing something?  (is not a problem of volume or mute).

The windows mixer doesn´t show the MIC level for playback (and cannot be enabled).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you should be able to open the mixer, and ensure the Mic is available (and not muted) for playback.  Usually it IS muted for playback by default to prevent feedback.

You may have to adjust the options of the mixer to actually show you the Mic's playback volume slider/mute button:

In XP you can do this in the Windows Mixer via the Options menu.

In Vista check Control Panel-->Hardware and Sound-->Sound-->Manage audio devices, go to the Playback Tab, select Properties.  In the Properties window, pick Levels to adjust volume and mute for the Mic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem is that the mixer doesn´t show  the mic volume level (in the options doesn´t appear unchecked either)

Comment: OK, apparently that Aspire ONE is a netbook with RealTek HD Audio. You'll need to check the Realtek control panel (should be in the Windows control Panel, or by clicking the 'other' speaker that Realtek likes to also put in the task bar). According to this v1.0 manual (http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/FileList/NewTech/2006_motherboard_newtech/hd_audio_driver_usermanualver1-00_0418-05.pdf) it should be under something similar to the "Mixer tab" and then you click the wrench to bring up the Mixer Toolbox window, which is where you can pick which volume controls are visible. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your Volume Control (Start->Run `sndvol32.exe`) will have a slider for your input device.  Typical names include *Microphone*, *Line In* or *Input Monitor*.  Make sure these are not muted and that to volume is turned up.

[image]

If you are not seeing one of these sliders, check in the **Options** menu under **Properties**.  Select the **Playback** radio button and make sure the *Microphone*, *Line In* or *Input Monitor* box is checked.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, howver I don´t have the "line in" option. I have reinstalled realtek drivers with latest version.