# How to play the sound from the microphone?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, microphone

I would like to amplify my voice using the computer. My Windows won't play the audio from the mic by default. How to configure it to do so? Should I use some app? Which one?

Comment: related question, but for windows xp: http://superuser.com/questions/95384/how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Windows 7 is slightly different from Windows XP

I had to check the "Listen to this device" box in the Microphone properties

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the level to 100 in the levels tab? Also in the advanced tab, select the highest studio quality option.

Comment: @Owen what for?

Comment: I dont suggest using "Listen to this device" (I don't know why but gives delay). Id suggest going to Devices > Speakers > Levels > and there turn on the microphone (this way there arent delay problems)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with translation (I don't have english windows) but i tried

open *control panel* - *sounds* - first tab (play), double click speakers and on second tab enable microphone.

Comment: enabling the mic is not enough

Comment: enable and set velocity, I hope it is enough